# Web.config backups

Tags: web-config, 2007, backup

Can we prevent the automated backup of moss web.config files or limit the number of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, SharePoint always create a backup of your web.config file before applying any changes. In development environments there can be a lot of these.

If you necessarily need to remove then create a script that removes the .bak files if they are older than X months.